# what happened to SDL_mixer.h?

Tags: xcode, macos, sdl

I am trying to get some open source C++ code to compile in xcode. It uses the SDL library. I [downloaded](http://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php) SDL 2.0 for OS X and installed it and things are working -- but the download didn't seem to include the file SDL_mixer.h -- which is referenced in the code, as shown below.

```
#include <SDL/SDL_mixer.h>
```

What happened to this file? Did it get dropped from SDL? What do I do to work around the missing file to get the code working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[SDL Mixer](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/) has always been a separate library you have to install next to your SDL.

To fix your problem, download and install the library in such a way that `SDL_mixer.h` is located in an SDL/ folder of your include paths.

Answer (score 1):

Install the [SDL Mixer](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/) framework and add a reference to it in your project.

Include the SDL_Mixer.h header like so:

```
#include <SDL2_Mixer/SDL_Mixer.h>
```